# Как адаптировать пример?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Пытаюсь разобраться как все же мышкой объекты передвигать. [Вот](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189066%28vs.95%29.aspx) что говорит документация.

Вот я делаю это переношу в [свой код](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?j3tht4dc2oh5).

Там двигают прямоугольник, я хочу двигать кнопку. Однако возникает вопрос.

Там пишут:

```
public void Handle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args) 
{
    Rectangle item = sender as Rectangle;
    if (isMouseCaptured) 
}
```

Что значит строка `Rectangle item = sender as Rectangle;` ? Что писать мне, если я кнопку создаю в мейне?

```
Button mybutton = new Button();
```

Далее:

```
item.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTop);
item.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLeft);
```

Тут по логике нужно писать так? :

```
mybutton.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTop);
```

Опишите мне словами и если можно код покажите, чтобы я понял логику работы этого всего...

Answer (score 2):

Все события в .NET присылают первым аргументом ссылку на объект-инициатор события. В случае с WindowsForms и WPF(Silverlight) это - ссылка на элемент управления, который и сгенерировал Event. Строка `Rectangle item = sender as Rectangle`
 - попытка приведения первого аргумента к типу Rectangle (то есть контрола-прямоугольника, в данном случае. У Вас этот код не сработает как надо, потому что инициатор - кнопка или окно, но никак не Rectangle). Второй аргумент - информация о самом событии.

Поскольку в Вашем случае, скорее всего, функция `Handle_MouseMove` подписана только на один элемент управления, `sender` Вам не нужен и можете смело писать так, как собирались, то есть явно указывать ссылку на свою кнопку.

Comment: А зачем приводить первый элемент к типу Rectangle и что будет первым элементом?

Не могли бы подсказать. Вот допустим я получаю координаты мышки. Как мне их перевести к координатам кнопки при перемещении?

Вот мой [код][1]


  [1]: http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?nqyhfbbvruj4

Comment: К типу приводят для того, чтобы получить доступ к методам самого типа. В примере, судя по всему, определялось, какой из элементов управления (прямоугольников) реагирует на мышь и затем с ним что-то делалось.

Для того, чтобы привести координаты мыши к координатам текущего элемента управления, нужно сделать примерно так:
    Point pos = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
В эту функцию передаётся как раз ссылка на объект, система координат которого нас интересует. Если это null, координаты будут абсолютными.

Comment: Я чуть-чуть подкорректировал Ваш код, но только уточнил там пару моментов, а о том, чтобы всё работало как ожидается, не думал. Может быть, когда появится время, поковыряюсь подетальнее :)

Comment: Я нашел один пример и засунул его в свой код, но сдается мне, что он в отрыве от кнопок получается. Как к нему кнопки прикрутить? Вот сам код http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?9rvjp6hthhqw

а вот откуда я его взял... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495408/how-to-drag-a-usercontrol-inside-a-canvas/1495486#1495486